# Update Excel/CSV file from List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, rest, jquery

I have a requirement in which suppose if someone adds an item in List, item details should be automatically updated to Excel/Csv file which has same column names as list.

This Excel/csv file can be in a library or on file system.

Is this possible? I have googled it a lot but could not find anything.

Answer (score 4):

The Excel file can be created for you automatically - there is no need to make a new Excel file yourself with headers to match the Sharepoint field names.  Try this: use the `Export to Excel` feature to take an extract of your list.

Save the Excel file, do not break the link (Unlink) - this will maintain a connection with changes made to the List.

[image: unlink]

You can upload your file and store it in Sharepoint so other users can share it.  The file can be refreshed with any modifications coming from the linked Sharepoint List.

### Refresh linked Excel file

To test refreshing the data, make a change to an item in your linked List.  Then open the Excel file and select `refresh all` - Excel will update to match with changes made in the List.

[image: refresh]

### Additional note

If you use the linked Excel file to create graphs, you can set up your file in such a way that the graphs will update when new data is available in the List.  When you refresh the file, it will refresh your graphs too.  Very useful for reporting of e.g. monthly KPIs.

### Updated

Make the Excel file auto-refresh when the file is opened.  See [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/refresh-connected-imported-data-e76a38b0-e2e1-400b-9f2f-c87b9b18c092) for details.

[image: auto refresh setting]

Comment: Although a great solution but As per the requirement we don't want to refresh it manually. And as per this solution we'll have to refresh it every time whenever we'll open the file. We want file to be updated all the time in library. Open it and find all the data, That's it.

Comment: Well, I am spoiling you by doing all the work, but I've updated my answer

Comment: Sorry for my last confusing comment. But I already have tried this approach but the problem is that the client does not even want to open the file. They are going to feed the file URL in a 3rd party tool which will read the data for them. So unfortunately this also will not help, at least in my case. Is there any other approach which can simply update the file, without even opening or refreshing the connection. Thanks for your time :)